# Discord bot on the disnake library

Tags: python

## Discord bot on the disnake library

**I tried to do something like this:**

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".",help_command=None, intents=disnake.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def copysticker(ctx, stickerid: int, guildid: int):
    try:
        sticker_id = int(stickerid)
        sourceguild = bot.get_guild(ctx.guild.id)
        destinationguild = bot.get_guild(guildid)
        sticker = await sourceguild.fetch_sticker(stickerid)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second to avoid rate limits
        await destinationguild.create_custom_emoji(name=sticker.name, image=sticker.image.read())
        await ctx.send(f"Sticker {sticker.name} copied to {destinationguild.name}!")
    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send('Invalid sticker ID provided.')
        return

bot.run("MTE...")
```

I can't do it I don't understand what the error is